# How to completely delete and app from iphone (including all the data and history)

Tags: applications, ios, history

So this problem particularly emerged with the Tinder app. I was using Tinder with a user account (A) and one day I logged out and created a new user account (B) which I never succeeded to activate due to sms verification problems, so I decided to login again with my old account. But even when I delete the Tinder app and reinstall it again, it still shows the B account logged in to the app. This means that IOS is somewhere storing a history for this app. Now I'm looking for a way to delete this history.

Note that this question is not necessarily about a certain app, but rather about where IOS stores historical data of apps and how to delete those histories alongside with the app.

**P.S:** If there are solutions like changing UUID of my i-phone that wouldn't damage my phone (I'm new to iphone so I'm not sure what I'm saying. For instance this jailbreaking thing which I keep hearing about and I'm not sure what it exactly does to my phone, doesn't sound like an I idea that I like), I'm open to them.

Comment: Tinder could be storing your device ID on their servers along with the 1st user ID.  Without jailbreaking or using 3rd-party apps from your computer, you can't delete that info from he device.  If you're open to this, please update your question so others will know they can provide answers with these options.

Comment: added a P.S. to my question, but I'm not sure if that's any helpful to readers.

Comment: I have the same problem!
We’re you able to solve it?

Answer (score 3):

Try deleting the app from within Settings and see if that makes any difference?

More specifically:

1. Go to Settings
2. Tap on General
3. Tap on Storage & iCloud Usage
4. Under the Storage heading, tap on Manage Storage
5. Wait for your list of apps to populate
6. Select Tinder
7. Tap on the red Delete App option
8. At the next prompt, tap OK
9. Exit Settings
10. Reboot your iPhone (press the Power and Home buttons for about 10 secs)

Now reinstall the Tinder app and see whether this process has made any difference.