# How to delete an app permanently with its history

Tags: iphone

I have an issue similar to one posted here before:
[How to completely delete and app from iphone (including all the data and history)](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/273940/how-to-completely-delete-and-app-from-iphone-including-all-the-data-and-history)

What can I do to fix it?

Comment: what is wrong with the answer n that post

Comment: Unless the app does something special, like save photos or send things to the cloud, deleting the app deletes the data too. All data is stored with the app.

Comment: Have you tried the solution from the answer beneath the original question? If it didn't work, what exactly didn't work? And which application do you want to delete? Please edit these additional details into your question so it can be reviewed and reopened.